# Jquery dragging tab

Tags: javascript, jquery

the below is a nice dragging tab, which I would like to implement in my project. Is there any jquery plugin for this.

http://www.blitzagency.com/our-people/#meet-the-blitizens

Answer (score 0):

The following tutorial is useful for you to try out, it uses Jquery and JqueryUI

http://jqueryfordesigners.com/slider-gallery/